# Trying to save loading times of an html inside a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a local `NSArray` of html strings. When the user moves back or fwd in the gui, with every tap a new html from the array is loaded into a `UIWebview`. Loading the html takes 1-2 seconds and this is what I'm trying to avoid. I thought about using 3 `UIWebviews` and load 3 html at a time but only show one `UIWebVIew` to the user. When the user will moves around the loading will seem instant. Can you think of a better idea doing that or am I on the right track?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. I suggest to reuse webview like UITableView reuse cells. If you want, you can take a snapshot of every webview the first time it is rendered and then show the image while you loading the webview the other time.